# Watson API (python-sdk) Using the V2 entity system for English NLU

Tags: ibm-watson

I'm using the Watson-developer-cloud python-sdk, and wish to use the Version 2 entity type system, for NLU in the English Language, but can't seem to do so.

Going over the documentation (link below), all versions under the English language have Version-1 as the entity system.
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/natural-language-understanding?topic=natural-language-understanding-entity-type-systems#entity-type-systems

Answer (score 0):

If an interface version for version-2 entities is not listed, then it is not provided. The document you refer to was last updated 21st Feb 2019, so it should be upto date.

Comment: Isn't it strange that English, the most common language for both industry and academia doesn't support version-2 entity system while other languages do?

Is the some estimation regarding when this support be available?